# Linux software to synthesize singing

Tags: linux, audio

I have some software to synthesize instruments, and some to synthesize speech. What I can't find is a program to generate singing (with or without a GUI).

I want to be able to input text and their notes, and get back an audio file.

Any recommendations?

**Note**:  Just "*any TTS program and then Autotune*" is an idea, but I don't know how well it would work.

Comment: What *exactly* do you need the software to do?

Answer (score 3):

This is *not* Linux-native (perhaps try Wine or a virtual machine?), but as far as I know the best software currently for synthesized singing is [Yamaha's Vocaloid3 product](http://www.vocaloid.com/en/lineup/vocaloid3/) (Windows, ~$100 for editor, $100-$200 for voices, some voices come with a license for a 3rd party editor):

- [Hatsue Miku](http://piapro.net/vocaloid/mikuv3e.html) (Windows/Mac, $150)
- [Magapoid English](http://www.ssw.co.jp/en/products/vocal3/megpoid/index.html) (Windows, $220)

<sub>There are many others, these seemed to be more geared towards English singing.</sub>

This is definitely the higher end of things, but the voices can sound [very good](https://www.youtube.com/watch?list=PLhZOHSOfxiL1lUfzv3rEUX3Ro2lh3-y-5&v=m7WyLhodvdE&feature=player_embedded).

Comment: I would be all for this answer if it were linux native. Although I don't feel it deserves to be downvoted, so i won't do that either.

Comment: As it mentions VOCALOID: so does [Linux MultiMedia Studio](http://vocaloid.wikia.com/wiki/Linux_MultiMedia_Studio). I'm not home in this area, so I cannot tell whether it would serve the topic; but it might be worth checking.

Answer (score 1):

Now there is at least this one: Dreamtronics Synthesizer V Studio https://dreamtonics.com/en/synthesizerv/

You can download a free or paid version. There are only two free voices that can sing English; Eleanor Forte (good) or Tsurumaki Maki (not useless). There are a few others that cost about as much as the paid version.

You have to install them separately by dragging their svpk files into the running application.

Here's a demo that uses Eleanor Forte: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o3XK9tw7DHI